# STAR PATTERN NOT PRINTING WELL

Tags: assembly, mips, instructions

I want to print star pattern in this way:

```
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

but it is printing this way:

```
******
******
******
******
******
******
```

Can someone help me? This is my code:

```
main:
        daddiu  $sp,$sp,-48
        sd      $31,40($sp)
        sd      $fp,32($sp)
        sd      $28,24($sp)
        move    $fp,$sp
        lui     $28,%hi(%neg(%gp_rel(main)))
        daddu   $28,$28,$25
        daddiu  $28,$28,%lo(%neg(%gp_rel(main)))
        sw      $0,0($fp)
        b       .L2
        nop

.L5:
        li      $2,6                        # 0x6
        sw      $2,4($fp)
        b       .L3
        nop

.L4:
        li      $4,42                 # 0x2a
        ld      $2,%call16(putchar)($28)
        move    $25,$2
        nop

        lw      $2,4($fp)
        addiu   $2,$2,-1
        sw      $2,4($fp)
.L3:
        lw      $2,4($fp)
        bgez    $2,.L4
        nop

        li      $4,10                 # 0xa
        ld      $2,%call16(putchar)($28)
        move    $25,$2
        nop

        lw      $2,0($fp)
        addiu   $2,$2,1
        sw      $2,0($fp)
.L2:
        lw      $2,0($fp)
        slt     $2,$2,6
        bne     $2,$0,.L5
        nop

        nop
        move    $sp,$fp
        ld      $31,40($sp)
        ld      $fp,32($sp)
        ld      $28,24($sp)
        daddiu  $sp,$sp,48
        j       $31
        nop
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey may be you are doing mistake in setting up loop in mips
You are not properly initializing the inner loop
if you are converting c program into mips than correctly set the limitation of inner loop

```
main:
        daddiu  $sp,$sp,-48
        sd      $31,40($sp)
        sd      $fp,32($sp)
        sd      $28,24($sp)
        move    $fp,$sp
        lui     $28,%hi(%neg(%gp_rel(main)))
        daddu   $28,$28,$25
        daddiu  $28,$28,%lo(%neg(%gp_rel(main)))
        sw      $0,0($fp)
        b       .L2
        nop

.L5:
        li      $2,5                        # 0x5
        sw      $2,4($fp)
        b       .L3
        nop

.L4:
        li      $4,42                 # 0x2a
        ld      $2,%call16(putchar)($28)
        move    $25,$2
        nop

        lw      $2,4($fp)
        addiu   $2,$2,-1
        sw      $2,4($fp)
.L3:
        lw      $3,4($fp)
        lw      $2,0($fp)
        slt     $2,$3,$2
        beq     $2,$0,.L4
        nop

        li      $4,10                 # 0xa
        ld      $2,%call16(putchar)($28)
        move    $25,$2
        nop

        lw      $2,0($fp)
        addiu   $2,$2,1
        sw      $2,0($fp)
.L2:
        lw      $2,0($fp)
        slt     $2,$2,6
        bne     $2,$0,.L5
        nop

        nop
        move    $sp,$fp
        ld      $31,40($sp)
        ld      $fp,32($sp)
        ld      $28,24($sp)
        daddiu  $sp,$sp,48
        j       $31
        nop
```

Comment: What is going on with this flood of answers to new and old MIPS questions from several different new users?  Did a class have an assignment to each answer a MIPS question on Stack Overflow or something?